# OpenAI Assistants API: How to get response from the /v1/assistants API endpoint in Postman?

Tags: postman, http-post, openai-api, openai-assistants-api

I created an assistant using platform.openai.com and am trying to access it from Postman.

POST: [https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/{assistant-id}/completions](https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/%7Bassistant-id%7D/completions)

Body:

```json
{
  "prompt": "Tell me a funny daddy joke about computers.",
  "max_tokens": 60
}
```

Headers:

> Authorization : Bearer API_KEY
> Content-Type : application/json
> OpenAI-Beta : assistans=V1

And getting response 404 Not found:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid URL (POST /v1/assistants/asst_EKb5utNB3oVKBHsZusxKKijO/completions)",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

If I try [https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/{assistant-id}](https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/%7Bassistant-id%7D)

Body : `{}`

I get all my assistant information. So it means my authorization works, but where is the problem with the first approach?

Comment: Can you provide a linke to the API documetastion for this usage of `completions`?

Answer (score 5):

You don't understand how assistants work. It's not that straightforward. You missed a lot of steps.

The following are steps you need to follow to get an answer from the assistant:

**STEP 1:** [Create an Assistant](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/createAssistant)

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants
```

**STEP 2:** [Create a Thread](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/threads/createThread)

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/threads
```

**STEP 3:** [Add a Message to a Thread](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/messages/createMessage)

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/messages
```

**STEP 4:** [Run the Assistant](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/runs/createRun)

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/runs
```

**STEP 5:** [Periodically retrieve the Run to check on its status to see if it has moved to completed](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/runs/getRun)

```
GET https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/runs/{run_id}
```

**STEP 6:** [Retrieve the Messages added by the Assistant to the Thread](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/messages/listMessages)

```
GET https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/messages
```

The following image from the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works/objects) is a nice visual example of how assistants work.

[image: Screenshot]

Also, I've made a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/F-KRs6vg4mM) on how to use the Assistants API and posted the [code](https://github.com/rokbenko/ai-playground/tree/main/openai-tutorials/2-Build_personal_math_tutor) on my GitHub profile.

Comment: Also, I missed, that the whole answer was in the test environment logs...

Comment: @RokasCvirka What do you mean? I don't understand.